# Vue Datepicker range in back

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuejs3

I use '@vuepic/vue-datepicker' library on my Vue 3 project. I try to create a date picker range where the user selects the first date and then selects a second date that was before the first date to reset and set the second one as a first. Also, want when the user selects a date in the range to show in the date picker input not wait to complete the range before inserting the range in input.

Example: Let's say the user selects 15.1.2023 as the first one and then selects 10.1.2023. Need to keep an open calendar and the first one be replaced with the second one and that change be visible in input.

Comment: Can you please provide the existing code?

Comment: @LastM4N it's not related to the code, but to the package. I can't find the option on the package in the documentation to disable the range to go back after the first date selected

Comment: You need to show your current code work in order to help you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a combination of these two options

https://vue3datepicker.com/props/general-configuration/#auto-apply
https://vue3datepicker.com/props/general-configuration/#close-on-auto-apply

Comment: Something like that is only for the range. If the user selects the first 15.4 and then 14.4 set 14.4 as from date. If the user again clicks 13.4 then that date will be from the date. Right now package works if you click 15.4 and then the 14.4 date picker calculates and sets 14.4 to from and 15.4 for to and that is the range.